# htaccess rewrite rule exclude directory from wildcard

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a htaccess with RewriteRule that if you access my domain it will direct to public folder. *See my code below*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Now I want to exclude demo directory (www.mydomain.com/demo) from the wildcard.
I try to use this code but didn't work

```
RewriteRule ^demo($|/) - [L]
```

and this

```
RewriteRule /demo/$1 -f
```

Full htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]

# Deflate Compression by FileType
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
</IfModule>

# Set browser caching to 1 month
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
 <filesmatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesmatch>
 <filesmatch "\\.(css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
 </filesmatch>
 <filesmatch "\\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
 </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Hope someone helps me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo` tests if the request uri is not starting with `/demo`, then apply the next `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I try to use above but didnt work here's my code

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]`

Comment: it does not exclude `/demo` folder? can you post your full .htaccess file in your question?

Comment: try to add `RewriteBase /` after the `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried it again but still didnt work here's my current htaccess code
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sequencing
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]`